# ffmpeg adts streaming with ezstream for icecast

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, audio-streaming, icecast

I'm trying to use ezstream to stream to an icecast server, my problem is while encoding the audio, I decode it from mp3 with madplay and I'm trying to encode it with ffmpeg so the output is aac, someone told me to use adts to be able to stream aac the problem is that the encoding doesn't stream the audio, it shows the timer on the console but it goes from 0:00:00 to 0:00:40 to 0:01:30, etc until the song ends instead of going second by second, this is my config:

```
<ezstream>
   <url>http://localhost:8100/t</url>
   <sourcepassword>password</sourcepassword>
   <format>MP3</format>
   <filename>/home/vybroo/server/audio/play.m3u</filename>
   <reencode>
      <enable>1</enable>
      <encdec>
         <format>MP3</format>
         <match>.mp3</match>
         <decode>madplay -b 16 -R 44100 -S -o raw:- @T@</decode>
         <encode>ffmpeg -f s16le -ar 44.1k -ac 2 -i - -b:a 32k -ar 44.1k -f adts -</encode>
      </encdec>
   </reencode>
</ezstream>
```

is the enconding config wrong?, what should i change so it streams second by second correctly

Comment: Im pretty sure that bitrate/samplerate/channels information needs to match up with your input stream files. not sure if this will help but here is a caption of mine...although I don't convert I do stream @the default `<svrinfobitrate>128</svrinfobitrate> <svrinfosamplerate>44100</svrinfosamplerate>`
It may be that these lines are still required.